# Are there any examples of serious websites using riot.js?

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I have scoured the internet (clicked next page on google a couple of times) and the riot.js docs, and can't find a single high traffic website that uses riot.js.

Are there any large scale websites/webapps using riot.js?

Comment: I'm shocked that a user with near 30K rep would ask a question like this.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [builtwith](http://trends.builtwith.com/websitelist/Riot)? I think the statistics aren't that useful, but there are listed some sites.

Comment: @AntiHeadshot that's great - answers my question today, and I am sure it will answer my questions in the future too - thanks!

Comment: I think this is a valid question too :$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear on http://libscore.com/#riot , so, no.